# Laravel Homstead project can't be reach on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

My Laravel project is working fine on firefox, but when i try it on Chrome i got "This site can’t be reached" and "Your connection with this site is not secure"

I'm using Homestead vagrant box and in .env file APP_URL: http://laravel-project.test

to be clear, project works in firefox, but is not reachable in chrome.
I tried to import the ca.homestead.homestead.pem file from vagrant (/etc/ssl/certs) to Chrome > Privacy and security > Security > Manage certificates / Manage HTTPS/SSL certificates (tab Authorities) > import...  and nothing has changed.

Does anyone have a similar problem or does anyone have an idea how to fix it as i need Chrome for debugging too?

Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because from the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Please delete this.